# Spring Data Neo4j: Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am doing stress testing of my Neo4j client which is built using **spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j**.

After sometime passed, application throwing error Unable to acquire connection for any request.

This is my bean configuration for Neo4j connection. can someone check and tell what can be done

```
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.0"



@Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    class Neo4jConfig(
        @Value("\${spring.neo4j.uri}")
        val neo4jDBUri: String,

        @Value("\${spring.neo4j.authentication.username}")
        val neo4jDbUserName: String,

        @Value("\${spring.neo4j.authentication.password}")
        val neo4jDbUserPassword: String
    ) : AbstractNeo4jConfig() {
//        https://medium.com/neo4j/try-and-then-retry-there-can-be-failure-30bf336383da
        @Bean
        override fun driver(): Driver {
            val config: Config = Config.builder()
                .withMaxTransactionRetryTime(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withLeakedSessionsLogging()
                .withRoutingTablePurgeDelay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withConnectionAcquisitionTimeout(2 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withConnectionLivenessCheckTimeout(2 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .withDriverMetrics()
                .withMaxConnectionPoolSize(100)
                .build()

            return GraphDatabase
                .driver(neo4jDBUri, AuthTokens.basic(neo4jDbUserName, neo4jDbUserPassword), config)
        }
    }

    // Refer: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4.0-M2-Release-Notes#neo4j-1
    @Bean(ReactiveNeo4jRepositoryConfigurationExtension.DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    fun reactiveTransactionManager(
        driver: Driver,
        databaseNameProvider: ReactiveDatabaseSelectionProvider
    ): ReactiveTransactionManager = ReactiveNeo4jTransactionManager(driver, databaseNameProvider)

    // Refer: https://hantsy.medium.com/data-auditing-with-spring-data-neo4j-11d6461146ff
    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    @EnableReactiveNeo4jAuditing
    internal class DataConfig {
        @Bean
        fun reactiveAuditorAware(): ReactiveAuditorAware<String> = ReactiveAuditorAware { Mono.just("Audit enabled") }
    }
```

Error message

```
webFilters.ControllerConfig in Neo4jDriverIO-2-2 - Returning HTTP 400 Bad Requestorg.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to acquire connection from the pool within configured maximum time of 120000ms; Error code 'N/A'   at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateImpl(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:105)    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at the following site(s):    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler 

controller.UserApiController#createUser(UserReqModel, Continuation) [DispatcherHandler]Stack trace:     at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateImpl(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:105)        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:91)      at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultReactiveNeo4jClient.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(DefaultReactiveNeo4jClient.java:271)       at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultReactiveNeo4jClient.access$200(DefaultReactiveNeo4jClient.java:54)        at org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.DefaultReactiveNeo4jClient$DefaultRecordFetchSpec.la
```

Comment: I cannot see your config but the `Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request` makes me wonder if you are connecting to the HTTP server (default 7474) or anything else instead of the Bolt port (default 7687)